# C# Naming Guideline for local variables

Tags: c#, naming-conventions, design-guidelines

A question about naming local variables in a C# method that takes a parameter of the same name
Please see the code below

```
 private int DoSomething(string activationCode)
    {
        ...

        int ??WhatNameToChooseHere?? = Convert.ToInt32(activationCode);

        ...
    }
```

What could be a good strategy to apply in the above scenario

Note: method paramter and local variable only differ by type only

Comment: If `activationCode` is always a valid `Int32` why not make the method only accept it as `Int32` and in places you need the actual `String` use `activationCode.ToString()`? You can even make an overload of `DoSomething` that accepts a `String`, converts that to an `Int32` and calls the other `DoSomething`.

Comment: A few projects I worked on used the convention `code` is a text, `id` is an integer number (`int`, `long`, `uint`, `ulong`). So we probably would've called it `activationId`. Don't know if that's a *good* convention, though, or if it should be applied here. Like I said, if it's an `int`, treat it like an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that. A proper way of doing it is to name your variables with different names.

Comment: The OP knows that he can't do it. He's asking what to do instead...

Comment: @JasonWatkins I believe this is Alan's suggestion for what to do instead: "name your variables with different names".

Comment: @JasonWatkins The OP modified his question, he originally had named his local variable and parameter the same exact thing and asked how to make it work. It is not my fault my answer doesn't match so well after he changed his question.

Comment: No, I read your answer before the OP edited his question. To me, it was quite clear that the OP knew he couldn't actually name them the same thing.

Comment: @JasonWatkins You're mistaken "method paramter and local variable only differ by type only". Check the revision history. It is not possible, and my answer tells him that he must name them differently. This is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
private int DoSomething(string activationCodeStoredInStringAndPassedAsAnArgument)    {
    int activationCodeThatDeclaredAsAnIntegerToStoreTheValueConvertedFromString = Convert.ToInt32(activationCodeStoredInStringAndPassedAsAnArgument);
}
```

Comment: While a bit facetious, this answer is fundamentally correct. Give your variables more descriptive names.

Comment: @JasonWatkins: Wow, you read my mind!

Comment: I just felt the need to spell it out for whoever down voted you.